# How to run QGIS server on EC2 micro?

Tags: qgis, server, amazon-ec2

I'd like to learn something about web maps and so decided to start out using EC2, following different tutorials I was able to start a micro instance but I can't find my way on how to get qgis server running. Any good tutorial to follow??

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed the tutorials you suggested but I always get stuck somewhere (usually I first have problems with "locale" and then I can get ubuntu "cgi" functionality) so I was wondering, is there anything more specific and step-by-step? thanks again

Comment: I think you'll be disappointed trying to run any GIS, especially a server, on an EC2 Micro instance.  These are not powerful machines and have a poor IO capacity.  You _can_ do it.  It's just that I don't think it's a great solution given the hardware limitations.

Comment: Thank for the comment and the editing. I get the point but my idea was to create a simple webmap to share, without any advanced GIS editing or geoprocessing

Comment: Here is my answer to my question: [link](http://www.cyberpuffs.com/2014/01/qgis-server-on-ec2-a-newbie-perspective/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tutorial: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial

Here's another: http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/da/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_server_support.html

I'd recommend using Ubuntu 12.04, you can find an EC2 image for that.

(Edit: fixed the second link)

Comment: I think it would be great if you can also post the relevant bits here. That way your answer will be self-contained and not be too dependent on external links.

Comment: I haven't actually done it myself, so I'd prefer not to write up a howto. I could write up something about EC2, but that is pretty basic and easy to learn...

Comment: Here is my answer to my question: [link](http://www.cyberpuffs.com/2014/01/qgis-server-on-ec2-a-newbie-perspective/)

Comment: The link above is dead, is there another newbie QGIS on EC2 tutorial anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: Fixed the link.